# How to stream http m3u8 playlist on https site?

Tags: javascript, http, https, jwplayer

Is there any way to use http m3u8 stream to use the stream on site with https?
I'm using JWPlayer and getting This video file cannot be played. (Error Code: 232012) error (A manifest request was made to an HTTP resource from HTTPS.    Cannot load M3U8: Unable to fetch HTTP resource over HTTPS)